# Email suggestion for a rogue email from my manager

Tags: work-environment, employee-engagement

Following scenario happened with me and my manager. Please suggest what should be the reply-email.

Recently, I fell sick on a Sunday eve and had to drop a sick leave email to my manager stating that I won't be available on Monday for work, due to personal health issues. On that, his reply was:

"Leaves should be planned accordingly and should be informed upfront so that we can plan the project activities. Take care of this in future."

Note that, this is not the first time he has dropped an email like this. Most of the time he thinks, the employees are bluffing. Earlier when I fell sick, he replied that, please be on leave with genuine reasons only.

I mostly dont reply on these and keep shut. But this time I have decided to make him listen me.

How would one know if they are going to fall sick!

P.S I'm a UI developer at one of the small tech company, have decided to resign from the job.

Comment: This question is very common but unfortunately the answer depends on a lot of factors: whee do yo live, how often are you sick, what kind of person is your manager, what is your realtionship ect ect. I don't think we can answer it.

Comment: We have all, at times, been sick enough that we know for a fact that we are not going to work the next day. Any reasonable person can understand that this is sometimes the case. That being said, it may save you a lot of trouble in the future if you simply send the email in the morning, rather than the night before. On paper, you're allowing the company more time to react to your absence, but in practice, a lot of petty individuals will doubt the sincerity of your emergency.

Comment: This verbatim sounds like my old boss, but in a different field. So I see that you're deciding to resign. Do you have a job lined up and a backup plan? If you can deal with this for a bit longer and then find another job in your free time, it would be better than the job search while being unemployed.

Answer (score 28):

Make it clear.

> I'm sorry for not being clear.  I am not well enough to work on Monday and will be off on sick leave.  I don't intend for this to be taken as vacation time.  I hope to be well enough to work in the next day or two.

By staying silent, you're silently agreeing with your boss's misunderstanding.

Comment: Also check the clarity of your initial email. I know we have all misread an email or two late at night and misconstrued something as a result.

Comment: You cannot stay silent in this situation unless you are content on agreeing.

Answer (score 4):

I think the key point is that you did not know until Sunday that you would be ill on Monday:

> I will indeed inform you as soon as I know I will be unable to work.
>   On this occasion I fell sick on Sunday evening, and e-mailed you as
>   soon as I knew I would be unable to work on Monday.

Comment: This sounds a little too much like you're apologizing. We have all, at times, been sick enough that we know _for a fact_ that we are not going to work the next day. Any reasonable person can understand that this is sometimes the case.

Comment: @AndreiROM, you're assuming a reasonable manager. I've worked with several unreasonable ones.

Answer (score 2):

1) Yes, definitely resign from this job (or look for a way to resign ASAP).  A manager who gets angry with his employees for being sick is not a manager, or a company (who supports this manager) you want to work for.

2) Inform your manager that you didn't know you were sick until Sunday evening, and that you could not have made plans earlier.  Depending on how cheeky you want to be, you may want to suggest to your manager that despite being sick, you can come into work anyway, although doing so would put the manager and everyone else in the office at risk of becoming sick as well.  If your manager demands you work despite being sick, then you should do so, but this should be an extra sign of getting out of there ASAP, as your manager has no care for the well-being of his subordinates.  You may want to raise this issue with HR as well, as this could be a company liability (as a company that does not take reasonable health-related precautions); HR is not your friend in general, but in this case they might be depending on your locale.